# Trying to run an Asynctask into a service, eclipse looks good, but app crashes Whats wrong here?

Tags: java, android, json, service, android-asynctask

Im trying to make an app witch looks on a JSON encoded php file, there that all right. All runs perfectly, but now im attempting to put that class into a Service beacuse i want to run it on background and repeatedly, but application crushes, (on the phone and simulated)

So can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Here is the code

First the main activity . java

```
[...]IMPORTS  
  public class ServiceMainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);
        }

        public void onClickComenzar(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
        }

        public void onClickDetener(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
        }

    }
```

And here the Service activity . java , the place where im trying to put my asynctask

```
package attempt.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;




import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {


            new DoBackgroundTask().execute("http://iatek.eu/sys/getsmsx.php");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "service stoped",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        @Override
         protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
             JSONObject obj = null;
             try{

                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
                   // HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString(); 
                    obj = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return obj;

             }

        protected void onProgressUpdate( ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
               JSONArray jsonArray;
               String dana = null;
                try {

                     jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
                     JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
                     String sms = childJSONObject.getString("sms");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms"+sms,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         stopSelf();
         }
        public StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
             String rLine = "";
             StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

             try {
              while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
               answer.append(rLine);
                }
             }

             catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
             return answer;
            }

    }


}
```

My objetive on this code is to show some php data on a toast, but it doesnt... i dont know why, help me pleasee!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add the exception that is shown?

Comment: It says "Aplication error, try later..." on a toast and then it closes

Answer (score 1):

I think using `InentService` is better suited for what you are trying to accomplish. It runs on a separate `Thread`, and it stops itself when it is done.

Comment: So can you send me and example link please? i dont know form where start :) thaks

Comment: It is used the same as a regular `Service`. Override `onHandleIntent()`.